# Let G be a group of order $p^n$ , p a prime. Show that $G$ contains an element of order p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Well, here's my Hypothesis. If G has an order of $p^n$, then its element has an order that divides $p^n$. If this is the case, isn't it already clear that G has an element of order p?

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to prove Cauchy's theorem. Yes, the order of an element of G has to divide its order $|G|=m$, but that does not mean every divisor of $m$ is the order of one of its elements, for any $m$. Lagrange's theorem does not have a full converse. You are being asked to show that it has a partial converse, ie, that this is true for when $m$ is prime.

Consider [this link](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchypf.pdf).

Comment: Cauchy is not necessary. See answer of @Bernard. You can even do induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Take any element $a\ne e$. By *Lagrange's theorem*, it has order some $p^s,\enspace s>0, \: s\le n$, and the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$  is cyclic, so all subgroups of $\langle a\rangle$  are generated by some power of $a$. Can you find one that has order $p$?

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck and didn't want to make a new question regarding this and was wondering if you could provide more insight

Comment: @user690808: Maybe I was too elliptic in this answer. Do the modifications make it easier?

Comment: Ah I think I understand! I just want to regurgitate just to make sure that all my points make sense. So suppose we take some x in G such that x is not the identity. Then the order of x must be p^s with p^s divides p^n. As <x> cyclic is contains subgroups of order all of the divisors of p^s and thus there exists an element of order p? As p divides p^s?

Comment: Yes. You just have to determine the correct power of $x$, knowing that $x$ has order $p^s$.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on that point? Why do we need to determine the power of x?

Comment: Because the elements of the subgroup generated by $x$ are powers of $x$. Its not hard, as you must have $\bigl(x^k\bigr)^p=x^{p^s}=e$

Comment: So we know that <X>= {e, x, x^2, ... x^(p^s-1)}? And then we just want to show that if we take some element in this group and raise it to p it is equal to x^(p^s)?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, yes, you have to determine which of these powers, raised at power $p$, will actually be $x^{p^s}$

Comment: Would that just be the element (x^p)^(r/p)? If there is a way to link files I can do that as well and send a picture if that would be more helpful

Comment: No. Another hint: you need to have $(x^k)^p=x^{p^s}$. Can't you deduce which value for $k$ will obviously work?

Comment: $(x^p^s-1)^p$ should work I think? Sorry I tried to mathjax it but it didn't come out well so k= $(p)^{s-1}$

Comment: Yes. I guess initially you missed a pair of braces at the right place…